# Docker network in compose: internal URL logic

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am looking at the following documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

and I do not understand why the URL to the container named `db` is `postgres://db:5432`. Why is the image name `postgres` used as a prefix? What would the prefix be, if I do not use a preset image but rather build from a dockerfile?

And why is the connection string from the host machine `postgres://{DOCKER_IP}:8001`? I thought that the

```
ports:
    - "8001:5432"
```

configuration would be equivalent to `docker run -p 8001:5432` and in that case I could always access the exposed port with `localhost:8001` or `{host_ip}:8001` if accessed from a different computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that URL, `postgres:` is the URL scheme; it's like the `https:` in `https://stackoverflow.com`.  It has nothing to do with the image name or even the detail of running in Docker at all.

You have a correct understanding of published `ports:`, and where the second example has `{DOCKER_IP}` it's a placeholder for the host system's IP address.  In some unusual circumstances (notably, using Docker Toolbox on some Windows systems) that will not be `localhost` but the address of a VM or some other system.

Another example, using an environment to specify a service URL:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  proxy:
    build: ./proxy
    ports: ['8080:80']
    environment:
      - BACKEND_URL=http://backend:3000
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    # ports: ['8081:3000']
```

Here the backend is an ordinary HTTP server and `BACKEND_URL` is an ordinary HTTP URL.  The Compose service name `backend` is the host part of the URL.  You don't specifically need to publish `ports:` but if you do the port to connect to is the *second* (container-internal) port number.  You do not need to declare `networks:`, and Compose will create a `default` network for you.

Comment: thank you - could you explain then, *why* postgres is the URL scheme? http and https are transfer protocols, right? But postrges seems to be a database and not a protocol and the only relation seems to be the image. So how does it come about? Is it always postgres?

Comment: That's [the URL format accepted by the PostgreSQL `libpq` library](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING).  It's not directly relevant to the mechanics of inter-container connections: the important thing is that, so long as two containers are on the same ("user", bridge- or overlay-type) Docker network (including the `default` one Compose creates) then their container names or Compose service names are valid host names to talk to each other.

Comment: it also appears to be valid to simply connect to `db:5432` in this case